# How to make random colors for embeds Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my Discord bot's embeds to appear in red or green (random between those two) so I want to create something that will make this possible.

I have the following code:

```js
const randomcolors = ['#008000', '#E50000']
const randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * foreigncolors.length));
```

Then I have this, but it always sets the color to green.

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(foreigncolors[colorss])
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to write something complex all by yourself. Instead, you can use:

```js
Embed.setColor('RANDOM')
```

This is an inbuilt feature of the `discord.js` library.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick a colour from an array of values, you can create a helper function and use that:

```js
function random(colors) {
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
};

random(['#008000', '#E50000']);
// => "#E50000" or "#008000"
```

In your example:

```js
const embed = new Discord
  .MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(random(['#008000', '#E50000']));
```

If you want to pick a totally random colour value, the `.setColor()` method accepts [specific colour strings](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ColorResolvable). One of them is 'RANDOM`, which sets the colour to a random value:

```js
const embed = new Discord
  .MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM');
```

Answer (score -1):

From the docs:

> The .setColor() method accepts an integer, HEX color string, an array of RGB values or specific color strings.

This means that we simply can generate an array of type `[R, G, B]` where each `R`, `G` and `B` are integer values between `0` and `255`.

```js
const randomBetween = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

const color = [
  randomBetween(0, 255),
  randomBetween(0, 255),
  randomBetween(0, 255),
];

console.log(color);
document.body.style.background = `rgb(${color[0]}, ${color[1]}, ${color[2]})`;
```